# Change Network IP Pool

Tags: ip

So I have this device that expects a server to be placed at this address `192.168.0.12`, and I have a network running on these addresses `192.168.1.X`.

So I've changed the network addresses to be on `192.168.0.X` and gave the server a static IP.

This solved the problem but I was wondering if there was a better option?

---

Edit: The device is a turnstile that controls the entries in a gym.

Comment: More info on the hardware involved might give more answers. As @Josh notes, what you did is the easy solution.  Not a bad thing

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is a perfectly acceptable way to solve the problem.  The other way would be to have your *device* configured to look for a server in the 192.168.1.x network.

Without knowing what the device is, that's about as specific as I can get.

Comment: The device I was talking about is a turnstile and i suppose it's server address should be impossible to change without being reprogrammed by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

A *better* solution is up to opinions.

An alternative solution would have been to temporarily change the network setting on one of your computers so you could connect to the device you mentioned. Then change that devices settings to match your network.

Comment: Like I commented in the other answer, I don't think I would be able to change anything on the device side.

Comment: If you an not reprogram the turnstile then you only have three options. Put a single device on both networks. (ugly), or do what you did, or call the manufacturer (may involve cost). What you did is probably the best under the circumstances.